# Ajax call not working in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have one function in java script. I want to send my form in ajax call after validation. I wrote ajax code for this but it's neither working nor giving any error on console even .

What can i do ?

javascript

```
  function resetValidation(){
    $(_reqForm).find('input, select, textarea, fieldset').removeClass('invalid');
    $(_reqForm).find('.error-indicator').attr('aria-hidden', true);
    $(_reqForm).find('#errorSummary').remove();
  }




  function handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formValid = true;
    var errorMessages = [];

        $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "quoteProcess.php",
  data : $('#testform').serialize(),

  success: function(data) {

            alert(data);
      //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); if the dataType is not     specified as json uncomment this
    // do what ever you want with the server response
 },
error: function() {
    alert('error handing here');
}    

            });
    $(_reqForm).find('#errorSummary').remove();

    $(_reqForm).find('[data-do-validate="true"]').each(function(){
      var validationResult = validateField($(this));
      if (!validationResult.isValid) {
        var fieldMsg = getFieldMessage($(this), validationResult.type);
        errorMessages.push({ elem: $(this).prop('id'), msg: fieldMsg });
        showFieldError($(this), fieldMsg);
        formValid = false;
      } else {

        clearFieldError($(this));

      }
    });

    if (!formValid) {
      if (settings.showErrorSummary) {
        showErrorSummary(errorMessages);
      }
      return false;
    } else {
      if (typeof(settings.submitFunction) !== 'undefined') {
        settings.submitFunction();
      } else {
        _reqForm[0].submit();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: it needs to be DOM-ready

Comment: @TheDefinitionist  Sorry

Comment: your handleSubmit starts the ajax to submit the data, and while that's happening only then does some validation - that doesn't look right at all regardless of the problem you're having

Comment: @JaromandaX
So what sequence i should follow to run validation first ?

Comment: If you only want to submit valid data, it makes sense to validate the data you submit ... I think ...

Comment: @JaromandaX

I want to submit my data after validation, where is should add ajax call in my code. Any Idea?

Comment: yes, you should put the ajax call after you've determined the validity of your input data

Comment: your code looks like a frankenstein of other peoples code .. references to _reqForm with no indication of what this even is, but the data you post early is gathered from a form with id="testform" - and with no html in your question, who knows what you should actually do

Comment: @JaromandaX
https://github.com/fraddski/attrvalidate/blob/master/attrvalidate.jquery.js  ......................
This is the code that i copied as such ...
Kindly see and suggest where we can add ajax call in it ?